# Notation for disjoint inequalities

Tags: inequality, notation

Is there a standard notation for representing disjoint inequalities? For example, let's say that I have an equation that may be solved under the following conditions:

$ x \leq a$ OR $ x \geq a+b$

is there a standard way to express an OR condition with inequalities? I thought of combining the two as:

$x \leq a \leq x-b$

But this is somewhat confusing because $a$ is a constant, and it looks like the upperbound is smaller than the lower bound. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation
$$x\leq a\leq x-b$$
means $x\leq a$ AND $a\leq x-b$, so you cannot use it. But writing it
$$x\leq a\quad\text{or}\quad x\geq a+b,$$
as you did, is a perfectly acceptable mathematical notation.